# Unable to get logger.info from another class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am using extent report for reports in html pages. Here i am facing an issue. I need to get logger.info message from another class. Please go through the below code you will get to know the issue and please correct me if i am wrong

### Class1: Reports

```
package test;

public class Reports {  
public  ExtentReports extent;
public  ExtentTest logger;

@BeforeSuite
public void startReport(){
        extent = new ExtentReports (System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/test-output/STMExtentReport.html", true);

              extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\extent-config.xml"));
            System.out.println("statrt report");

}


@AfterMethod
public void getResult(ITestResult result){
    System.out.println("In ITresults : After method");
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE){
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getName());
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getThrowable());
    }else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP){
        logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test Case Skipped is "+result.getName());
    }

    extent.endTest(logger);
}
@AfterSuite
public void endReport(){        
            extent.flush();               
            extent.close();
}
```

}

### Class2 : - NewTest1

```
package testng;

public class NewTest1 extends Reports {
@Test
public void failTest(){
    System.out.println("NewTest1 --> in Test fail testcase ");
    logger = extent.startTest("failTest");
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
    logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case (failTest) Status is failed");
}

@Test
public void passTest(){
    System.out.println("NewTest1 --> in Test pass testcase ");
    logger = extent.startTest("passtest");
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
    logger.log(LogStatus.PASS, "Test Case (passtest) Status is failed");

   skipTest();

}
```

Class3 :- NewTest2
    package testng;

```
public class NewTest2{
//static ExtentReports extent;
 static ExtentTest logg;


public static void skipTest(){
    System.out.println("NewTest1 --> in Test skip testcase ");  
    logg.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test case info will come here");    // Getting Nullpointer exception here
    throw new SkipException("Skipping - This is not ready for testing ");
    }
```

}

Comment: Waiting for the answer and i appreciate in advance.

Comment: You end the test in your AfterMethod so after one test case, it's closed.

Comment: yes, but skipTest in NewTest2 class is part of passtest in NewTest1 class. It should close after executing the skiptest method ryt..